# How do I remove all style tags without jquery

Tags: javascript

Its simple, it removes all style tags on everything
This code below does exactly what I want to

```
$('*').removeAttr('style');
```

now I need to do the exact same thing without jquery, since my whole code is written 
without jquery, I don't want to include the library for this simple task

> among other things, this is what I tried so far but it won't work

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').style.cssText = null;
document.getElementsByTagName('*').style.cssText = "";
document.getElementsByTagName('*').removeAttribute("style");
```

---

solution

```
    var allstyles=  document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var a=0; a<allstyles.length; a++)
    {
        allstyles[a].removeAttribute("style");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` returns an array. You need to go through each item individually in a loop and remove the attribute.

An example of such a loop could be

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].removeAttribute("style");
```

Comment: It's actually a collection, not an array - but yes, the answer is correct (might want to add an example though).